# How to position an elemement right next to the screen edge?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I think it will be best to show what I’d like to achieve on an example:

```css
header {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</header>
<main>
Sed ullamcorper ligula sapien, eget congue risus iaculis eget. Etiam nunc diam, hendrerit nec nisi non, tristique feugiat risus. Donec maximus enim lacus, eget iaculis lectus aliquam non. Aenean id egestas justo, vitae placerat nulla. Suspendisse a tempor ipsum. Donec condimentum varius diam. Praesent mollis tincidunt nibh, sit amet euismod lacus mollis et. Nulla in condimentum elit. Quisque eu hendrerit nunc, id auctor risus.
</main>
</body>
```

As you can see, this blue `header` is not positioned right next to the screen edge, since the `8px` margin that `body` has applies. I would like `header` to disregard this margin and `main` to still have it.

I can see three ways to achieve his:

**Giving `header` `position:absolute;`**

But this leaves no space for the subsequent text:

```css
header {
    background-color:blue;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</header>
<main>
Sed ullamcorper ligula sapien, eget congue risus iaculis eget. Etiam nunc diam, hendrerit nec nisi non, tristique feugiat risus. Donec maximus enim lacus, eget iaculis lectus aliquam non. Aenean id egestas justo, vitae placerat nulla. Suspendisse a tempor ipsum. Donec condimentum varius diam. Praesent mollis tincidunt nibh, sit amet euismod lacus mollis et. Nulla in condimentum elit. Quisque eu hendrerit nunc, id auctor risus.
</main>
</body>
```

I’d have to manually move `main` down so that it leaves space for `header`. But how the heck can I know how much space does `header` need, especially if the screen is resized and the beginning paragraph wraps?

**Give `header` `position:relative;` and negate the margin.**

That’s a close one:

```css
header {
    background-color:blue;
    position:relative;
    top:-8px;
    left:-8px;
    margin-right:-16px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</header>
<main>
Sed ullamcorper ligula sapien, eget congue risus iaculis eget. Etiam nunc diam, hendrerit nec nisi non, tristique feugiat risus. Donec maximus enim lacus, eget iaculis lectus aliquam non. Aenean id egestas justo, vitae placerat nulla. Suspendisse a tempor ipsum. Donec condimentum varius diam. Praesent mollis tincidunt nibh, sit amet euismod lacus mollis et. Nulla in condimentum elit. Quisque eu hendrerit nunc, id auctor risus.
</main>
</body>
```

But is it in a good style do do something like that? Also, can I be sure that all browsers give `body` exactly an `8px` margin?

**Remove the margin of `body` and manually give it to all subsequent elements.**

Probably the closest one:

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

header {
    background-color:blue;
}

main {
    margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</header>
<main>
Sed ullamcorper ligula sapien, eget congue risus iaculis eget. Etiam nunc diam, hendrerit nec nisi non, tristique feugiat risus. Donec maximus enim lacus, eget iaculis lectus aliquam non. Aenean id egestas justo, vitae placerat nulla. Suspendisse a tempor ipsum. Donec condimentum varius diam. Praesent mollis tincidunt nibh, sit amet euismod lacus mollis et. Nulla in condimentum elit. Quisque eu hendrerit nunc, id auctor risus.
</main>
</body>
```

Any better ways to do this than this?

Comment: if you don't want the body to have a margin, why don't you just add `body { margin: 0; }` to the css?

Comment: The third one is the best maybe use `padding` is another option but is still the same logic ... really don't get your question if you already have the solution. This could be primarily opinion

Answer (score 0):

you can add `margin: -8px -8px 0 -8px;` to your header element

Comment: this assumes a default `<body>` margin of `8px (0.5rem)`

Comment: @Martin I might be wrong but I think default body margin is fixed 8px.

Answer (score 0):

The last solution is the best according to me because that is the natural way to do that and if you want to give padding to the other contents then you can use a div for that, in most websites you will see all professionals follow that.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know that the margin that body uses is `8px` you could try following:

```
header {
    background-color:blue;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
```

Try it here https://jsfiddle.net/h1uhfzv2/3/